# is it a common practice to refer to a complexity of O(mn) as O(n^2) with no known relation between m and n?

Tags: time-complexity

I had a computer science test in school and we were asked to give the complexity of a code we had to write. the complexity was undoubtedly O(mn) where m,n were unrelated to each other. I got deducted some points as I should've assumed m=n and therefore the complexity is O(n^2). I was later told we were taught to do so and I guess that regardless of whether I'm right or not I'm in the wrong here (I learned some computer science long ago so I was paying too much attention in class). but is there any reason such assumption should be done apart from making it easier for high school pupils?

Comment: Double check that these $m,n$ are indeed unrelated (or show us this mystery algorithm).

Comment: To answer your question, I am afraid that it is *common wrong practice*.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no relation between $n$ and $m$, then $O(mn)\neq O(n^2)$.

To illustrate this, think for example what would have happened if we assumed someone would have put an input with some $n$ and  $m=2^n$. In this case, the complexity could be thought of as $O(2^n\cdot n)$. Is that equal to $O(n^2)$? **No!**

What about if we assume someone always inputs an $m=5$? Then the complexity is $O(5n)=O(n)$, which is smaller than $O(n^2)$.

As we can see from the examples, since there is no known relation between the two variables, one cannot convert this $O(mn)$ to any other form containing only one variable.

Answer (score -2):

An upper bound $O$ notation is used to describe an upper bound for the function growth, i.e. the growth will never be greater than what $O$ says. So in your case $O(mn)$ think about how you can maximize the term $mn$ such that any combination of $m$ and $n$ can never be greater than the maximized function. For this particular case you can think of it as maximizing the area of a square with sides $m$ and $n$. You would get the maximum area when $m=n$ and hence $O(n^2)$ is a more appropriate upper bound(with $n$ being $max(m,n)$).

Comment: You get maximum area when $m=\infty$

Comment: wouldn't my argument still hold?

Comment: $n = \max(m, n)$ makes sense while programming, but not that much in math: it would be more rigorous to use a different letter. For example, $\mathcal{O}(mn)\subset \mathcal{O}(N(m, n)^2)$ with $N(m, n) = \max(m, n)$. Note that here, $N$ is not a variable but a function.

Comment: Your argument is very confuse, sorry, and $O(mn)$ is not bounded by $O(n^2)$.